# wso2bam 2.4.0 running ibm jdk 7

Tags: wso2

I am trying to configure wso2bam-2.3.0 to run on an IBM 1.7 JDK so that I can gather statistics from a wso2am-1.6.0 instance. The product documentation indicates that IBM JVM's are supported however after following the integration setup steps to get the api manager and bam talking to each other I get an exception when starting up bam.

```
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.DataBridgeException: Cannot start agent server on port 7711
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.internal.ThriftDataReceiver.startSecureEventTransmission(ThriftDataReceiver.java:129)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.internal.ThriftDataReceiver.start(ThriftDataReceiver.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.internal.ThriftDataReceiverDS.activate(ThriftDataReceiverDS.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:517)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)
Caused by: 
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.TransportException: Thrift transport exception occurred 
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.internal.ThriftDataReceiver.startSecureEventTransmission(ThriftDataReceiver.java:150)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.internal.ThriftDataReceiver.startSecureEventTransmission(ThriftDataReceiver.java:127)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: 
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Error creating the transport
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createSSLContext(TSSLTransportFactory.java:201)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.internal.ThriftDataReceiver.startSecureEventTransmission(ThriftDataReceiver.java:146)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: 
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunX509 KeyManagerFactory not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:171)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.java:10)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createSSLContext(TSSLTransportFactory.java:184)
    ... 65 more
```

This same exception occurs for a base wso2bam install. I have found references to this issue in for version 2.0 M5 (http://wso2.com/mailarchive/carbon-jira/2012-June/051761.html) however no workable solutions were found for version 2.4.0. The issue appears to be a tight dependency to the Sun JDK for the SunX509 algorithm. Has anyone got a workaround/fix for this issue or know how to configure BAM to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the BAM 2.4.0 doesn't support IBM JDK.

According to [BAM-502](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BAM-502), the solution is to upgrade the thrift version. However the BAM 2.4.0 still uses the thrift 0.7.0. The thrift bundle in BAM is [libthrift_0.7.0.wso2v2.jar](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/dependencies/orbit/libthrift/0.7.0.wso2v2/pom.xml), which is inside `wso2bam-2.4.0/repository/components/plugins` directory.

I increased the priority of the JIRA. Therefore BAM team *may* consider to upgrade thrift version in next release.

Easiest workaround is to use Oracle JDK 7. However I'm not sure if that's feasible for you.

Next workaround is to patch the thrift version in WSO2 BAM 2.4.0. It *seems* to be a simple [fix](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blobdiff;f=lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TSSLTransportFactory.java;h=044e06ab372babbde5c990e84238f36fc27abdac;hp=1e1c4c99bb2b47a63753263c01468e16011faf92;hb=6bac11f4fa3d96acdbd9e625be11f4f97aa053bc;hpb=1b13083defbde2dae2baf535eeae272c7c9e1ab0). `TSSLTransportFactory` should be updated to use default algorithms as follows.

```
protected String keyManagerType = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
protected String trustManagerType = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
```

However it might not be easy to patch. You can try this, if you really need to run the BAM 2.4.0 on IBM JDK 7.

You need to checkout thrift 0.7.0 source and patch it. After patching you can build [libthrift_0.7.0.wso2v2.jar](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/dependencies/orbit/libthrift/0.7.0.wso2v2/pom.xml) and copy it as a [patch](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/WSO2+Patch+Application+Process) to BAM 2.4.0.

I hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Isuru, I patched the libthrift jar and followed the patch process however BAM doesn't seem to be seeing my changes. I can see the libthrift jar being patched but it seems like another version is being loaded. I patched the createSSLContext method in the TSSLTransportFactory.